# Exception: blockingConnect must not be called on the UI thread despite, I subsribed on another thread

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I have invocation like this:

```
 val connectionResult = googleApiClient.blockingConnect()
```

which is cause of this exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: blockingConnect must not be called on the UI thread

```
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbp.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbd.blockingConnect(Unknown Source)
at com.elstatgroup.elstat.NexoLocationManager.startLocationUpdatesGmsApi(NexoLocationManager.kt:510)
at com.elstatgroup.elstat.NexoLocationManager.startLocationUpdates(NexoLocationManager.kt:498)
at com.elstatgroup.elstat.NexoLocationManager.appendRSSIEvent(NexoLocationManager.kt:283)
at com.elstatgroup.elstat.NexoLocationManager.appendRSSIEvent(NexoLocationManager.kt:273)
at com.elstatgroup.elstat.NexoLocationTest.testAppendLocationEvents(NexoLocationTest.kt:111)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$HelperTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:497)
at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.evaluate(SandboxTestRunner.java:228)
at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner.runChild(SandboxTestRunner.java:110)
at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner.runChild(SandboxTestRunner.java:37)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$1.evaluate(SandboxTestRunner.java:64)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

I thought, that this will help:

```
 Observable.just(googleApiClient.blockingConnect())
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                    .subscribe(Consumer { connectionResult ->
                        if (connectionResult.isSuccess()) {

                //do something
                     }
                    })
```

But i am wrong and this not help.
The only way i make it not crash is this:

```
         Thread(Runnable {
                val connectionResult = googleApiClient.blockingConnect() 
                if (connectionResult.isSuccess()) {
                    //do something
                }
            }).start()
```

So why my RxJava solution not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Observable.just()` accepts value(s) which is/are passed to next chained observable. If you examine carefully, then in your case here

```
Observable.just(googleApiClient.blockingConnect())
```

`googleApiClient.blockingConnect()` gets executed first as `just` operator needs a value/values. So you need an operator here that accepts a function call or something like that.

For your case `Observable.fromCallable()` can be used which receives a callable as a parameter:

```
Observable.fromCallable(() -> googleApiClient.blockingConnect());
```

Here `googleApiClient.blockingConnect()` will execute when you subscribe to observable chain.

Answer (score 1):

This is because Observable#just is eager and will block untill #blockingConnect finishes.

This example should do the trick:

```
    Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
        return googleApiClient.blockingConnect();
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
```